# Overloading >> operator to read in text file

Tags: c++, io, overloading

Have this code for overloading the >> to read a text file:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, AlbumCollection &ac)
    {
        std::ifstream inf("albums.txt");

        // If we couldn't open the input file stream for reading
        if (!inf)
        {
        // Print an error and exit
            std::cerr << "Uh oh, file could not be opened for reading!" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        // While there's still stuff left to read
        while (inf)
        {
            std::string strInput;
            getline(inf, strInput);
            in >> strInput;
        }
```

Called by:

```
AlbumCollection al = AlbumCollection(albums);
cin >> al;
```

The file is in both the source directory and in the same directory as the .exe but it always says that it can't fine the file. Sorry if the answer is really obvious, this is the first time I've tried reading in text a file in C++; I don't really understand why this isn't working and the online help I can find doesn't seem to indicate that I'm doing anything wrong....

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? where do you get the error?

Comment: why are you *not* using the ac variable from within the function ? And why are you exiting from an operator overload ??

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: I'm trying to read in data from the file "albums.txt".

Comment: I just do not understand why you read it from `inf` and then overwrite all the data read with data from `in`.

Comment: @SirDarius: Because this was developed from originally developed as a readFile method.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: Neither am I, come to think of it....

Comment: if you want to print something, use an `ostream` and not an `istream`, which as the name indicates is an input device. C++ standardizes the `<<` operator for these operations, not the opposite.

Comment: @SirDarius: It shouldn't be printing anything; that's an error in the commenting more than anything.

Comment: @TheGeneral: The points being suggested are that *context* of what you're doing here is not really suitable for a stream input overload. However, that doesn't really help you with your file that won't open. Have you tried creating a really basic file open example, for this file? I.e. no stream operators, just the `ifstream` constructor and the following conditional check.

Comment: You have an input operator which reads both from a file _and_ overwrites what it reads from the file with what it reads from the passed input stream. The input operator should _not_ open the file, instead you should open it in e.g. the `main` function, and use the file together with the input operator. The input operator should use only the passed input stream to read input.

Comment: @Component10: Yeah, I'm aware that what I'm doing here is a bit wierd here and I'm gonna need to rewrite it to make it work sensibly as a stream input overload. yes, The real problem is that I have no idea why it won't let me read a file; that is the actual question here. The rest was posted to give context (which was probably a bad idea in hindsight given how bad the code currently is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check the working directory. When specifying a file by its relative path, the relative path is always considered as relative to the working directory. For example, you can print the working dir by using the function `getcwd()`.

You can change the working directory in the settings from the project properties of the IDE.

Some remarks:

- Do not exit from an extract operator.
- You're overwriting the content of `inf` by the content of `in`.
- `cin` is usually not for files.
- You're missing the return of the stream.

In fact, a better version of your operator would be:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, AlbumCollection& ac)
{
    std::string str;
    while(in >> str)
    {
        // Process the string, for example add it to the collection of albums
    }
    return in;
}
```

How to use it:

```
AlbumCollection myAlbum = ...;
std::ifstream file("albums.txt");
file >> myAlbum;
```

But for serialization/deserialization, the best I think is to use functions in `AlbumCollection`:

```
class AlbumCollection
{
    public:
        // ...
        bool load();
        bool save() const;
};
```

This method allows your code to be much more self-descriptive:

```
if(myAlbum.load("albums.txt"))
    // do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better way of implementing it and, even better, I think I actually understand how it works!

Answer (score 2):

If you run the program from your IDE it might be that the IDE's current directory is aimed at somewhere else than your exe directory. Try running the EXE from the command line. Try also give a full path to your file, in order to be sure that it can find it.

A little bit of the subject, although C++ allows for operator overloading, I don't encourage this, for the very simple reason - it makes it difficult to search for the declaration of the operator overloading in the code! (try searching for `operator >>` for the specific type...). Also editors with `go to declaration` feature don't handle this so well. Best is to make it a normal function,

```
std::string AlbumsToString (AlbumCollection &ac)
```

which returns a `string` which you can concatenate to your stream:

```
mystream << blah << " " << blah << " " << AlbumsToString(myAlbums) << more_blah << endl;  // !!!
```

You can use `ostringstream` inside `AlbumToString` to build the string stream-like, and eventually return the `str()` member if `ostringstream`.